# Horizon - Ingest historical trade history for pair

Tags: horizon

Is there a way to ingest data for `trade_aggregations` for asset pairs instead of needing to ingest all the ledgers into Horizon? I only really care about `trade_aggregations` on specific pairs and don't need all the other history.